# Hide chart in Pentaho Report Designer if not data

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

We are setting a chart on Pentaho Report Designer 5.3 and we want it to hide if no data is returned by the query, aligned to that chart.

We have used, the:

```
=NOT(ISEMPTYDATA())
```

in the visible style expression but it shows

```
chart_user_no_data_available
```

on the chart, and it is not working.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function that returns true/false. True means "have data", False means "No Data". Then, write in the visible style expression the following code :

```
=YourFunction
```

Comment: Give more explanation please